# Segue error: due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, segue, avkit

I am trying to turn on Segue by pressing a button. Before I added this code it worked but after adding the code (code that triggers a video by clicking on a button) the code crashes my application with the following error:

> due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fatB.

I searched for the error and I understand that its mean that `Xcode` cant find some name (fatB)
But I can't figure the rest out.

Below is my code:

**viewcontroller1 code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func movieB(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "firstsegue", sender: self)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var winnerLabel: UILabel!
}
```

**viewcontroller2 code:**

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    func forbutton(name : String, type : String)  {
        func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            playVideo(name: name, type: type)
        }
    }

    private func playVideo(name : String, type : String) {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(name)", ofType:"\(type)") else {
            debugPrint("video not found")
            return
        }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        present(playerController, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }        

    @IBAction func fatB(_ sender: Any) {
        forbutton(name: "fatB", type: "mp4")
    }

    @IBAction func coderB(_ sender: Any) {
        forbutton(name: "birdC", type: "mp4")
    }

    @IBAction func clashB(_ sender: Any) {
        forbutton(name: "clash", type: "mp4")
    }
}
```

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is nested in another method. Move it to the top level of the class.

Comment: The issue is that the method doesn't get parameters and I need different parameters for each button, am I able to do that?

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is called by the framework, don't call it yourself. If you want to pass parameters Implement `prepare(for segue` in the first view controller.

Comment: The problem is solved but the videos don't is this because the reason you specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because:

1) You have removed a `IBOutlet` from your code but not from `Controller's scene` in `Storyboard`.

2) You may have changed the name of your `IBOutlet` reference variable.

Please check your `Controller's scene` in Storyboard and remove the unused `IBOutlet` reference or update it with the new reference variable name.

Answer (score 1):

check connections inspector. there is an IBOutlet with named fatB. remove it from there

It may be an UIButton

Comment: It's one of the necessary video playing buttons (how can i replace him?)